# Как добавить в Bootstrap4 свои брекпойнты?

Tags: bootstrap

При добавлении кастомной точки останова, ничего не работает. Есть варианты?

Это файл медиа-запросов:

```
// ≥1200px
 +media-breakpoint-down(lg)

// ≥992px
 +media-breakpoint-down(md)

// ≥768px
 +media-breakpoint-down(sm)

// ≥576px
+media-breakpoint-down(xs)
```

Это файл переменных Bootstrap

```
$grid-breakpoints: (
   xs: 0,
   sm: 576px,
   md: 768px,
   lg: 992px,
   xl: 1200px
 ) !default;
```

Answer (score 0):

создал отдельный файлик _custom.scss и подключил его в самом верху файла bootstrap.scss

```
 @import "custom";
```

Содержимое моего файла примерно такое:

```
    $grid-breakpoints: (
   xs: 0,
   sm: 576px,
   md: 768px,
   lg: 992px,
   xl: 1200px,
   new: 1600px
 );
```

new - новый брейкпоинт.

Можно поменять значения у существующих и даже их удалить.
После этого сгенерировать новую сборку bootstrap.